# In Android, some cell phones work the graphical interface perfectly, and other cell phones do not the same graphical interface. For what reason?

Tags: android, user-interface, responsive-design, responsive, responsiveness

I'm developing a code on Android, and testing it on two cell phones of different brands. Sorry these screens are not in English language, okay?
You can see that in the screenshot below, it's from a mobile phone brand A. It's showing the GUI without any problem.

[image]

In the screenshot below, it's from a brand of cellphone B. And it's showing the **SAME** Graphical Interface with problems:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/corDeFundo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoDosSintomas1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="501dp"
        android:text="@string/textodossintomas"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/doresNoCorpo"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textoDosSintomas1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-450dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
        android:text="@string/doresNoCorpo"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/perdaDePaladarOuOlfato"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/doresNoCorpo"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-48dp"
        android:text="@string/perdaDePaladarOuOlfato"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/dorDeCabeca"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/perdaDePaladarOuOlfato"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
        android:text="@string/dorDeCabeca"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/diarreia"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dorDeCabeca"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="196dp"
        android:text="@string/diarreia"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botaoPaginaAnterior2"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/diarreia"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="229dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/seta_esquerda"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botaoProximo2"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/diarreia"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/seta_direita"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the following screenshot of mobile brand A, it is showing the Graphical Interface without any problems:
[image]

In the following screenshot of mobile brand B, it is showing the **SAME** Graphical Interface with problems:

[image]

Please what can I do to fix it?
Maybe it's not a problem with XML, as on mobile brand A, the GUI is working without any problems.

Is there any programming code that facilitates Responsiveness (ie adapting to different screen sizes) on Android please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you should not be setting a fixed width for those checkboxes.  Make them match_parent and allow them to fill the space they need to fit the text.

Additionally, even if you do this it isn't guaranteed to take the same space on all devices-  users can change the size of the font in settings.  People with vision problems use that to be able to actually see your app.  You should write your layout to help make this possible, not try to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see your xml so I'm going to assume you set

```
android:layout_width="xdp"
```

So you can change it to

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

If this is not the case please edit your question and add your xml

Comment: Hello, Taa Lee. Thank you very much for your answer. I put the source code of the first code, ok? :)

Comment: Yes, so if you want your app to work on different cell phones properly you cannot use fixed width and sometime heights instead work with match_parent or wrap_content and add weight not to mention android already have more sizes available for example ?actionbarsize to fit in different situations . I can see your problem is with using relative layout. I recommend to change it to linear layout with vertical orientation and if its still too big you can make parent scroll view. That is for now till you have the time to google about different layouts and the best usage for you and your app

Comment: After using linear layout with vertical orientation you wont need the excessive use of margin and your layout will work properly